# Integrating unity AR with react native (Desperate)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, augmented-reality

Hi I have developed a unity AR model and I want to integrate it with my React Native app that I have been building. All the solutions do not work... Looking for any sort of help or guidance please... (I'm new to AR as well)

This ship is sinking...

Tried

1. React native view github repo
2. Exporting unity AR as a native app for android(compile android compileSdkVersion) and IOS(need to pay)